# "Destroy" a a DragShadowBuilder

Tags: android, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I'm making an app with a drag and drop functionality. What basically happens is you can move Views from one container to another via drag and drop. However, when I reset the positions of the views programmatically, the DragShadowBuilders created during the drag and drop retain their positions and are still visible.

How can I "destroy" or deactivate a DragShadowBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider trying the `invalidate()` function in [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) to force a redraw of the view containing the dragged view and its shadow. If the drag is over, the shadow shouldn't be redrawn.